# Problema al cancelar la eliminación de comentario

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Mi intención es crear una página de eliminación de comentarios a la que se puede acceder mediante un enlace de otra. La cuestión es la siguiente:
Si confirmo la eliminación funciona perfectamente, pero si al salir el cartel pulso en cancelar no se muestra el aviso de que se ha eliminado pero el registro se borra igualmente, cosa que se supone que no debería pasar, simplemente tendría que volver a la página anterior. Este es mi script para realizar esa operación(la idea es que el cartel de confirmación salga nada más acceder a la página).

```
                <script>
                    function confirmacion() {

                      var confirmar = confirm("¿Eliminar el comentario?");
                      if (confirmar == true){
                        <?php
                        $borrarcom=$conexion->prepare("DELETE  from comentarios WHERE id_comentario=?");
                        $borrarcom->bind_param("i", $id_comentario);
                        $borrarcom->execute();
                        $borrarcom->close();
                        echo'window.alert("Comentario eliminado")';
                        ?>
                      } 


                        window.location="javascript:history.back(-1)";

                    }
                    //llamada a la función para que aparezca el cartel nada más acceder a la página
                    confirmacion();

                    </script>
```

Aclaración: El id de los comentarios se toma de la URL

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

**el archivo quedaria:**

```
$id = $fila["id_comentario"];
echo "<a onclick='confirmacion({$id})'>eliminar comentario</a>";
```

**el javascript quedaria:**

```
function confirmacion(id) {
    var confirmar = confirm("¿Eliminar el comentario?");
    if (confirmar == true) {
        // envia una peticion ajax con el id
        fetch(`eliminar.php?id=${id}`)
        .then(response =>response)
        .then(response =>{ if(response == 1) alert(`Comentario eliminado`); })
        .catch(error=> console.log('Hubo un problema con la petición Fetch:' + error.message));
    }
    window.location = "javascript:history.back(-1)";
}
```

**y el php eliminar.php:**

```
<?php
$id_comentario = filter_var($_GET["id"], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$borrarcom=$conexion->prepare("DELETE  from comentarios WHERE id_comentario=?");
$borrarcom->bind_param("i", $id_comentario);
if($borrarcom->execute())
    echo 1;
$borrarcom->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Estas mezclando cosas y te estás liando tu solo.

Tu código PHP, tal y como lo tienes, **se ejecutará siempre**, lo cual quiere decir que **siempre se va a borrar el comentario**.

Esto:

```
<?php
$borrarcom=$conexion->prepare("DELETE  from comentarios WHERE id_comentario=?");
$borrarcom->bind_param("i", $id_comentario);
$borrarcom->execute();
$borrarcom->close();
echo'window.alert("Comentario eliminado")';
?>
```

Se ecuta en tu servidor **siempre que se renderiza la página**, **INDEPENDIENTEMENTE** del JavaScript que muestras. Para comprobarlo, basta con que comentes tu llamada:

```
// confirmacion( );
```

Verás que, aun así, el comentario **se borra igualmente**.

Tendrás que realizar el borrado de comentarios usando AJAX u algún otra técnica.

Answer (score 2):

Me funciona usando este código(por si alguien tiene el mismo problema)

```
<?php 
echo '<td><a onclick="return confirm(\'¿Eliminar comentario?\')" href="Delete.php?id_comentario=$fila[id_comentario]">Borrar comentario</a></td>' 
?>
```

(Previamente definiendo los valores de $fila en un bucle while)